# How to get the name of the file containing the class?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get the name of the file containing the class? The variable `exporter` is a class in the below.

```
def main(exporter):

    v = exporter
    print v # <__main__.Vudu object at 0x106ea5210>
            # The class is "Vudu" and the filename that contains that class
            # is called vudu_exporter. How would I get "vudu_exporter" ?
```

**Update**: The following works to get the name of the script containing the class:

```
script_name = os.path.basename(inspect.getfile(v.__class__))
```

Comment: `vudo.vudu_exporter.__file__` should contain its name.

Comment: What class? You haven't shown us any classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`inspect.getfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) on the class/function/method/module. It's not guaranteed to work, but it's more reliable than just checking [the `__file__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) of the object (for example, on Python 3.5, `inspect.getfile(collections.defaultdict)` works, while `collections.defaultdict.__file__` raises `AttributeError`).

If you have an instance, this won't work without converting to the class first, e.g. `inspect.getfile(type(instance))` (on Python 2, `instance.__class__` can be more reliable with old-style classes); it can only tell you where the class was defined, not where the instance was defined.